# Hibernate not working

Tags: manjaro, hibernate

I am using Manjaro, and out of the box hibernation was not working, so I made some changes to fstab, mkinitcpio and grub and it worked but after sometime it doesn't hibernate and instead locks the screen, even though after a restart it works fine and yes I have made the swap twice the size of my RAM. Please help I couldn't find this exact question anywhere online.

Comment: What are the changes you made to the files that you mention, that made it work?

Comment: In /etc/fstab added:
    UUID=[UUID_of_the_swap_partition] none swap defaults 0 0
    In /etc/default/grub added:
    resume=UUID=[UUID_of_the_swap_partition] to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX
    In /etc/mkinitcpio.conf added:
    resume to HOOKS (after udev)
    sudo mkinitcpio -P && sudo update-grub

Comment: You may want to add that to the question instead, as a clarification, using the formatting tools provided to make it readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How you can fix it...

```
sudo swapoff -a
sudo /sbin/mkswap /dev/sd##(swap)
sudo swapon -a
```

In `/etc/fstab` add:

```
UUID=[UUID_of_the_swap_partition] none swap defaults 0 0
```

In `/etc/default/grub` add:

```
resume=UUID=[UUID_of_the_swap_partition] to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX
```

In `/etc/mkinitcpio.conf` add:

```
resume to HOOKS (after udev) sudo mkinitcpio -P && sudo update-grub
```